# how can i group php array by certain key value

Tags: php, arrays

i get a array that look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CAT] => CAT
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DOG] => DOG
            [3] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CAT] => CAT
            [4] => 1
        )

)
```

but what i want is soemthing like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CAT] => CAT
            [2] => 1
            [4] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DOG] => DOG
            [3] => 1
        )
)
```

Comment: how did you get the first array? or is it the starting array you have?

Comment: `foreach ($tipe as $key => $value) {
    $db = new MysqliDb ('pets');
    $db->where("pet_type_ID='$value'");
    $per_tipe = $db->get("Animals");

     if(!empty($per_tipe)){

      foreach($per_tipe as $values){
        $animal_array=array();
        $animal_array[$values['Pet_name']]=$values['Pet_name'];
        $animal_array[$values['pet_type_ID']]=count($values['pet_type_ID']);
        $animal_arrays[] = $animal_array;
      }
    }
}`

Comment: sorry heres the begging `$db = new MysqliDb ('pets');
$pets_types = $db->get("pet_type");
foreach ($pets_types as $key => $value) {
    $tipe[$value['pet_type_ID']]=$value['pet_type_ID'];
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created it in a way to save keys and everything. Let me know if it works out for you :)

```
<?php
    $start = [
        ["cat" => "cat", "2" => 1],
        ["dog" => "dog", "3" => 1],
        ["cat" => "cat", "4" => 1]
    ];
    $end = [];

    foreach($start as $key => $array) {
        if(!isset($end[current($array)])) {
            $name = current($array);

            $end[$name][key($array)] = $name;
            next($array);
            $end[$name][key($array)] = current($array);
        } else {
            $name = current($array);

            next($array);
            $end[$name][key($array)] = current($array);
        }
    }

    $end = array_values($end);

    print_r($end);
```